# Transform spark df to df of subsequent pairs

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm trying to achieve is to transform a Spark df of integers into df of pairs connecting each subsequent elements like that:

```
[1, 7, 9, 10, 11] -> [(1, 7), (7, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11)]
```

I don't know any Spark transformation allowing that.
Maybe there is some map variation allowing to peek the next element? Or perhaps using RDD would allow such operation?

In Scala Spark I would I would represent my input as:

```
val input = Seq[Int](1, 7, 9, 10, 11)
val inputRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(input)
val inputDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputRdd).toDF("point")
```

The result I'm looking for would be an rdd with two columns.

Comment: this is not a df

Comment: @mck I updated the question with df input

Comment: spark dfs are unordered. The "next" element is not well defined.

Comment: If you had a way of determining the order of the elements, you could create a dataframe and then run sql query over it similar to `SELECT point, LEAD(point) OVER() as point2 FROM input`. [Spark window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html)

Comment: @botchniaque Thank you for the suggestion. 
If I order by point value, I belieive:
`SELECT point, LEAD(point) OVER(ORDER BY point) as point2 FROM input`
would order be maintained through whole dataset, or just locally?

Comment: the `OVER(ORDER BY ...)` determines the ordering of the items in window. Which mean the `LEAD(point)` will return the next smaller point value. This is universal across all SQL engines - have a look at some window function tutorial.

Comment: but taking a step back - what I believe you're trying to do is to join a rdd of numbers with itself where `t1.index = t2.index + 1`. What you're missing here is the index of each element .